# Updating database in MySQL to SQL server in LightSwitch

Tags: c#, switch-statement, visual-studio-lightswitch, ls, light

I have my LS with datasource made in MySQL. I decided to create same database in SQL Server, and when I use the "Update DataSource" of LS, all of my screen objects gone (the textboxes, labels, codes, etc.).

See Image.

[image]

Now my question is, how can I retain the screen objects even I change/update my datasource?
Is it possible? Or I have to recreate my screens?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're going to have to recreate your screen objects. LightSwitch V1 doesn't have the ability to change "change" a screen's data source & still keep the existing screen objects, nor does it have a way to copy/paste screen elements either.

Sorry I had to be the bearer of "bad news".

We're hoping that scenarios like this will have been improved in V2.